# Docker container giving Internal Server Error on using .htaccess

Tags: php, docker, apache, .htaccess

When i run my app in docker contaner with out htaccess it works perfectly. But when i add .htaccess to the rewrite rule it is causing internal server here. I also granted permission to apache vhost but still the result is same.

**Here is my dockerfile**

```
FROM php:7.2-apache

RUN apt-get update

RUN apt-get install -y wget lsb-release gnupg2

RUN echo "deb http://packages.couchbase.com/ubuntu bionic bionic/main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/couchbase.list

RUN wget -O - http://packages.couchbase.com/ubuntu/couchbase.key | apt-key  add -

RUN apt-get update

#RUN apt search libcouchbase

RUN apt-get install -y  libcouchbase2-libevent libcouchbase-dev

RUN apt-get update

RUN pecl install https://packages.couchbase.com/clients/php/couchbase-2.6.2.tgz 

COPY ./config/php/php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/

#WORKDIR /var/www/html/

#COPY ./pos/backend/ /var/www/html/pos/backend/

RUN chown www-data:www-data . -R

RUN a2enmod rewrite

EXPOSE 80
```

**Here is my docker-compose**

```
version: '3.1'

services:
  php:
    container_name: php_apache
    depends_on:
      - db
    build:
      context: .
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    restart: always  
    volumes:
      - ./config/vhosts:/etc/apache2/sites-enabled
      - ./backend/:/var/www/html/

  db:
    image: couchbase:community-6.6.0
    container_name: couchbase_server
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
    volumes:
      - ~/couchbase/node1:/opt/couchbase/var
    ports:
      - 8091:8091
      - 8092:8092
      - 8093:8093
      - 8094:8094
      - 11210:11210
```

**here is my htaccess file**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f   ls
  RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]  
</IfModule>
```

**vhost file apache default.conf**

```
<Directory /var/www/>
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Comment: Do you get any error message?

Comment: Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at [no address given] to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Apache/2.4.38 (Debian) Server at localhost Port 80

Comment: *More information about this error may be available in the server error log* is there anything in there?

Comment: Actually i am new to docker dont know where to get logs. What i tested is when i remove .htaccess file app is working

Comment: I am using codeignitor for my backend

Comment: The server logs are usually in `/var/log` within a folder in there -- usually http

Comment: Open a shell in your container with `docker exec -it XXXXXXXXX /bin/bash` (change X's with container ID hash from `docker ps`). Then investigate apache logs in `/var/log/apache2`.

Comment: I may be missing something, but usually Dockerfiles have a CMD or ENTRYPOINT line to indicate what program/service to run. For instance, the official Apache Dockerfiles have `CMD ["httpd-foreground"]`

Comment: @HansKilian see the base image ~ `php:7.2-apache`. It has `CMD ["apache2-foreground"]`

Answer (score 1):

Dont know whats happening but i found this on google and it solved my issue . Incase if some face same

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```